# A memory leak, could my problem be with pointers [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, stream

iOS 12.x Swift 5

I am using sockets to talk to another box and I wrote this code which I think makes sense. but I wanted to check with an expert. I ask cause I think I have some sort of memory leak with this app. And I suspect pointers, as you do. I am watching the memory it uses slowly increase as I am running it.

```
func sendMessage(message: String) {

    let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let dataMutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
    //Copies the bytes to the Mutable Pointer

    dataMutablePointer.initialize(to: 0)
    data.copyBytes(to: dataMutablePointer, count: data.count)

    //Cast to regular UnsafePointer
    let dataPointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(dataMutablePointer)

    //Your stream
    outputStream.write(dataPointer, maxLength: data.count)
    defer {
      dataMutablePointer.deinitialize(count: data.count)
    }
}
```

Does this code look sane? Could it be the source of my memory leak? Do I need to deinitalize this pointer?

Comment: You may need to explicitly call `deallocate` to remove your pointers when you're done to avoid memory issues. It looks like you're using `deinitialize`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer/2949292-deallocate

Comment: Can I deallocate in the defer statement? Obviously I don't want it to unallocated the memory before the stream has finished with it.

Comment: I'm not certian. But I would think you can call that anywhere your `dataPointer` or `dataMutablePointer` is in scope.

Comment: You can use `defer { dataMutablePointer.deallocate() }` as long as you want the deallocate to always happen when you leave scope. Also, you only need to call `deinitialize(count:)` on non-trivial types so you could remove that call in this context if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Could it be the source of my memory leak?***

Yes, surely.

***Do I need to deinitalize this pointer?***

As commented by bscothern, you need to deinitalize the pointer if the `Pointee` is non-trivial type. But in case of `UInt8`, it is not mandatory.

But you **need to deallocate the pointer** eventually.

Your code would be something like this:

```
func sendMessage(message: String) {

    let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let dataMutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
    defer {
        dataMutablePointer.deallocate()
    }

    //Copies the bytes to the Mutable Pointer
    dataMutablePointer.initialize(to: 0)
    defer {
        //This is not required, but you can put `deinitialize` here if you prefer
        dataMutablePointer.deinitialize(count: data.count)
    }
    data.copyBytes(to: dataMutablePointer, count: data.count)

    //Cast to regular UnsafePointer
    let dataPointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(dataMutablePointer)

    //Your stream
    outputStream.write(dataPointer, maxLength: data.count)
}
```

`defer` defers the execution of its block until the end of the enclosing block, so `dataMutablePointer.deallocate()` will be executed after `outputStream.write(dataPointer, maxLength: data.count)` is finished.

But I would write something equivalent without copying data:

```
func sendMessage(message: String) {

    let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    data.withUnsafeBytes {bytes in
        let dataPointer = bytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        //Your stream
        outputStream.write(dataPointer, maxLength: data.count)
    }
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
func sendMessage(message: String) {
    //Your stream
    outputStream.write(message, maxLength: message.utf8.count)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to write this out. Is my solution more thread safe than your optional one or are they much the same. There are multiple processes on the other side writing to stream, so in theory sendMessage could be called before it is finished with the first message.